# How to permitAll anonymous access in Spring Boot 3 or above?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

After upgraded to Spring Boot 3.0.0 from 2.7.6, public API are not accessible.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return web -> web
                     .ignoring()
                         .requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest)    
                         .requestMatchers("/actuator/**", "/graphiql/**", "/voyager/**", "/vendor/**", "/rest/**",
                             "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there: move `requestMatchers` with `permitAll` to `SecurityFilterChain` definition (and remove `WebSecurityCustomizer`):

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
            .requestMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll() 
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
        .build();
}
```

Also, make sure the configuration class containing your `SecurityFilterChain` bean declaration is decorated with `@Configuration` (set a breakpoint or log line to ensure it is instantiated).

Few notes:

- never disable CSRF protection if you don't also disable sessions with `http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`
- CORS is configured with SecurityFilterChain too: `http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())`
- you might need to map roles or groups or whatever your authorization-server populates as private-claim to Spring authorities by providing your own `jwtAuthenticationConverter` to JWT `oauth2ResourceServer` configurer

You can do all of above with no Java conf (just a few properties) with [thin wrappers](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) around `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` I wrote:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public static class SecurityConfig {
}
```

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://localhost:8443/realms/master
# This is adapted to Keycloak with a client-id spring-addons-public. Replace with the claim(s) your authorization-server puts roles into
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,resource_access.spring-addons-public.roles

# you might want something more restrictive as allowed origins (accepts a list), at least for a part of your endpoints
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/**
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].allowed-origins=*
```

Complete (short) tutorials there (with spring libs only or "my" wrappers): https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Comment: Added `.requestMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll() ` still getting unauthorised error.

Comment: Need more info about the error and the rest of your app.

Comment: Please also specify what your request is.

Comment: Last, check that your security conf is loaded (set a breakpoint or a log line). Maybe you just forgot to decorate your configuration class with `@Configuration`.

Answer (score 2):

The methods have not changed too much.

Sample :

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // ...
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize                                  
            .requestMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()         
            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                             
            .requestMatchers("/db/**").access(new WebExpressionAuthorizationManager("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')"))   
            // .requestMatchers("/db/**").access(AuthorizationManagers.allOf(AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasRole("ADMIN"), AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasRole("DBA")))   
            .anyRequest().denyAll()                                                
        );

    return http.build();
}
```

Provided of https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html

EDIT : To complete my answer, you have access to all methods, so to set up a resource server you need to add this :

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain web(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // ...
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize                                  
            // ...                                                
        )
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer( OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt )


    return http.build();
}
```

Remember to add the variables corresponding to your OAuth2 provider

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://{your-ouath2-provider}/{issuer-uri}
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://{your-ouath2-provider}/{jwk-uri} (optionnal)
```

The links depend on your oauth2 provider.

For more information about the resource owner server
: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html

Comment: Any ides of how to implement the same with OAuth2?

Comment: For resource server only ?